# Laravel 8 login attemp special characters (error?)

Tags: laravel, authentication, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

Login code in my authController is:

```
$data = $request->validate([
    'password' => 'string|required',
    'name' => 'string|required'
]);

if (auth()->guard()->attempt($data)) {
    $user = auth()->user();
} else {
    return response('not auth', 401);
}
```

the prolem is when I try to login with credentials:
name: **Bak**
and
name: **Bąk**
and both of them are correct ... but shouldn't.

Do You have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's down to MySQL, rather than Laravel. If you echo the $request->name that comes in to the authController you will see that at that point it respects the difference between Bak and Bąk.

If, however, you create a user with the firstname "Bąk" and then use :

```
User::where('firstname', 'Bak')->first();
```

to retrieve it from the database, it will match your user with the firstname "Bąk" as well, which is why both are showing as valid. That's because under UTF-8 collation (which your database is almost certainly set to) Bąk and Bak are seen as one and the same.

Answer is to change the collation for that (and any other fields which may have this issue) to utf8_bin to make it use the binary comparison. I've tested that on a dev set up and it respects the distinction.